# Is there a way to get a flexbox to fill all available height?

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a browser like environment and I need to make a container dynamically fill all available space.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
/* user agent stylesheet */
html {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 10px;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: var(--uxp-body-font-size);
    color: #505050;
}

/* my stylesheet */
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.content {
   background-color: lightblue;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="content">content</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I set the html tag height to 100% then it does sortof work but I don't know if I can set that because it's a controlled environment (edit: I can set the html height to 100% and it sort of working).

Comment by @tacoshy if he doesn't put this in a comment:

> "Set body to 100vh"
>
> That causes a few issues. First, you have an instant overflow
> because you didn't reset the default body margin.
> Second, you get an overflow issue as you used a fixed height instead of a min-height.
> Third you miss an actual explanation of why the issue is caused.
> Last but not least you miss a property to let the other elements fill the remaining space (flex-grow);

Comment: What do you mean by `controlled environment`?

Comment: If the flex parent has a determinable height then yes, otherwise, no. In this case, you need to set the height of the `html` element to 100% also.

Comment: body by default si set to `fit-content` Means it will size depending on the content. To fill a remaining space you need a container which is larger then the content. After that you should look into `flex-grow` to which you have hundreds of duplicates alone on SO.

Comment: @AnasAnsari It's a plugin environment with most but not all browser feature set

Comment: @Paulie_D It looks like setting HTML height to 100% is doing something

Comment: I've updated the example code to include the user agent stylesheet. The HTML element is display flex.

Comment: @tacoshy Can you undelete the answer Saurav gave? It is great to see why that doesn't work. It is exactly what I thought to do. It helps to see your comment describing why that doesn't work.

Comment: If you set html height to 100% then it will occupy 100% height of whatever you are using to display this. I don't see the problem with that. You would need to explain the situation if this is not going to work

Comment: @Huangism I think I got it to work by setting the HTML to 100% but there are a few other problems now. I'm sorting through that. I've posted an answer.

Comment: Probably best to post a different question if you get stuck with something else

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is caused because the default height of the body being set to `fit-content`. As such it will calculate its own height depending on the content. The next issue is, that `height: 100%` means 100% of the parent's height. By default, the `<html>`-tag is set to `fit-content` as well. So the height is undefined and 100% of undefined is also undefined. Therefore the body's height is undefined as well even though you set it to 100%.

The Flexbox is applied to the wrong container. You have to apply it to the direct parent of the element you want to let fill the remaining space. Logically the parent needs a height larger than the child as otherwise, the child can't grow to the parent's height (that we covered above).
To let the child element grow to fill the remaining height you can use `flex-grow`.

The technique to solve the issue is quite simple:

1. You need to apply the flexbox container to the body as the body contains the visual content: `body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`
2. to fill at least the viewport you apply a `min-height` of `100vh`. If you set a fixed `height` then you can run into overflow issues and need to add an overflow rule: `body { min-height: 100vh; }`
3. This causes an overflow issue by default as most browsers have a default body margin of 8px. So you overflow by 16px. You can't sue `calc(100vh - 16px)` as not all browsers have the same body margin. Easiest solution is to reset the body margin: `body { margin: 0; }`
4. Since you use flexbox you can use `flex-grow` to let an element occupy the remaining space: `main { flex-grow: 1; }`

Note that I replaced the div for header and content with the correct semantic tags. This is necessary for screen readers and as such accessibility. Without semantic tags, a screen reader won't know what those elements are and not be able to tell a user with a disability what those elements are for.

```css
/* my stylesheet */
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>content</main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as a partially working example to not edit the original example.

The part that works is the html body is now fully filling the available space. The part that is not working is in my environment the items are spaced out.

```css
/* user agent stylesheet */
html {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: var(--uxp-body-font-size);
    color: #505050;
}

/* my stylesheet */
body {
margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 33px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="content">content</div>
   </body>
</html>
```